# Mock patch results in error -- TypeError: object() takes no parameters in python 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, mocking, django-unittest

This is a bit complicated because I'm debugging some code written a long time ago in python 2.7

In progress of migrating to Python 3 (I know, I know) and facing this problem when trying to fix unit tests

The problem is I'm getting an error `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

I'll list the functions below. I have to replace a lot of names of functions and objects. If you see an inconsistency in module names, assume it's typo.

First the class it's calling

```
class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self, some_instance, some_file):
        self._some_instance = some_instance
        self.stream = Parser.formsomestream(some_file)
        self.errors = []

    @staticmethod
    def formsomestream(some_file):
        # return a stream


class BetterParser(Parser):

    def parse(self):
        # skip some steps, shouldn't relate to the problem
        return details  # this is a string

class CSVUploadManager(object):
    def __init__(self, model_instance, upload_file):
        self._model_instance = model_instance
        self._upload_file = upload_file
    # then bunch of functions here
    # then.....
    def _parse(self):
        parser_instance = self._parser_class(self._model_instance, self._upload_file)
        self._csv_details = parser_instance.parse()
        # bunch of stuff follows
    def _validate(self):
        if not self._parsed:
            self._parse()
        validator_instance = self._validator_class(self._model_instance, self._csv_details)
        # some attributes to set up here

    def is_valid(self):
        if not self._validated:
            self._validate()
```

Now the test function
    from somewhere.to.this.validator import MockUploadValidator
    from another.place import CSVUploadManager

```
class TestSomething(SomeConfigsToBeMixedIn):
    @mock.patch('path.to.BetterParser.parse')
    @mock.patch('path.to.SomeValidator.__new__')
    @mock.patch('path.to.SomeValidator.validate')

    def test_validator_is_called(self, mock_validator_new, mock_parse):
        mock_validator_new.return_value = MockUploadValidator.__new__(MockUploadValidator)
        mock_parse.return_value = mock_csv_details
        mock_validator_new.return_value = MockUploadValidator()

        string_io = build_some_string_io_woohoo()  # this returns a StringIO
        some_file = get_temp_from_stream(string_io)

        upload_manager = CSVUploadManager(a_model_instance, some_file)
        upload_manager.is_valid() # this is where it fails and produces that error

        self.assertTrue(mock_parse.called)
        self.assertTrue(mock_validator_new.called)
        validator_new_call_args = (SomeValidator, self.cash_activity, mock_csv_details)
        self.assertEqual(mock_validator_new._mock_call_args_list[0][0], validator_new_call_args)
```

As you can see, the CSVUploadManager takes in the a django model instance and a file-like obj, this thing will trigger `self._parser_class` which calls `BetterParser`, then `BetterParser` does its things.

However, I'm guessing it's due to the mock, it returns `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

My questions:

1. Why would this error occur?
2. Why only happening on python 3.x? (I'm using 3.6)
3. This also causes other tests (in different testcases) to fail when they would normally pass if I don't test them with the failed test. Why is that?
4. Is it really related to mocking? I'd assume it is because when I test on the server, the functionality is here.

EDIT: adding Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/path/to/test_file.py", line 39, in test_validator_is_called:
    upload_manager.is_valid()
  File "/path/to/manager.py", line 55, in is_valid
    self._validate()
  File "/path/to/manager.py", line 36, in _validate
    validator_instance = self._validator_class(self._model_instance, self._csv_details)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: You need to share the traceback

Comment: @IainShelvington added traceback

Answer (score 0):

There should be 3 mock arguments, except self. 
Like this:

```
@mock.patch('path.to.BetterParser.parse')
@mock.patch('path.to.SomeValidator.__new__')
@mock.patch('path.to.SomeValidator.validate')
def test_validator_is_called(self, mock_validate, mock_validator_new, mock_parse):
   ...
```